# Syncing Overleaf to access .tex files in Dropbox

Tags: overleaf, dropbox

I'm writing a paper in Overleaf. I'm running the analysis in R, using stargazer to output latex code in a .tex file that is stored in Dropbox.

Is it possible to get Overleaf to sync with the .tex file uploaded to Dropbox? It would just be so great if when I re-ran my analysis in R, and updated the .tex file of the results, I didn't then have to manually reupload the file into Overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is https://support.overleaf.com/forums/137318-feedback/suggestions/5440927-automatic-two-way-sync-to-dropbox in the overleaf support forum, not sure how far this has gone. But given one can't really find anything else useful on that matter, I guess one could say there is no Overleaf-side implementation now. The have git if that helps you: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/195-new-collaborate-online-and-offline-with-overleaf-and-git-beta#.WwFegiBpFPY

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.) Overleaf v2 now has two-way Dropbox sync. To try out Overleaf v2, see https://www.overleaf.com/blog/641-try-out-overleaf-v2

Comment: Just to add to @liantze-lim 's response, I believe that option is available on overleaf v2 but only for paying users, not for free users.

Comment: One more limitation for the Dropbox sync (@LianTzeLim please correct me if I am wrong) ==> upon setting up the Dropbox sync, Overleaf will achieve TWO-WAY SYNC to a _designated folder_: **~/Dropbox/Apps/Overleaf**. I did not find a way to pick an arbitrary file in Dropbox and have the file itself synced to a project on Overleaf.

Comment: @llinfeng Yes, that is correct: at present it's not possible to specify which Dropbox folder you want to sync your Overleaf projects to—sorry!

Comment: @LianTzeLim, Thank you for confirming and looking forward to an update :)

Comment: By the way, this seems to be a real limitation as Dropbox does not let you share Application folders. This means that your co-authors on a project cannot edit offline, or is there a workaround?. @llinfeng

Comment: @JacquesCremer: I bet this is part of their business model? To bring co-authors onto the project, the "best" way is to _invite_ them directly to the Overleaf project. This brings new active users to Overleaf and is actually beneficial for the research team: Overleaf shall handle the conflicts introduced by concurrent edits in a professional manner. Sharing over Dropbox's Application folder, on the other hand, is intended for a single user who has multiple computers?

Comment: @llinfeng On some projects, you sometimes want to work concurrently with the co-authors and sometimes use another technology when you know the others are not working on the project (I love BakomaTex which is much more responsive than Overleaf for editing).

Comment: @JacquesCremer: I think we are now talking about off-line editing. Or, say, to directly edit the `*.tex` files ==> I agree with you that local tools are a lot more responsive than Overleaf. As of now, I think Overleaf presents two viable options: 1. through Dropbox, where Overleaf writes two-ways to a dedicated folder under `~/Dropbox/Apps/Overleaf/Project_Folder`; and 2. through Git repository ==> one can find the address for the git-repository on Overleaf and can start from there to save the Project_Folder anywhere on his/her computer.

Answer (score 2):

As many answered as comments, it is possible to sync with Dropbox (since overleaf v2, end of 2018), see  [Working Offline in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Working_Offline_in_Overleaf).

It seems there are several constraints:

- You need to pay for that, i.e. have the "Professional" account. Note some universities or companies might give you this
- This will place your overleaf in a given folder in `~/Dropbox/Apps/Overleaf`, which you cannot change it seems
- That dropbox folder can only be shared as *view only*, i.e. with a link you provide to others, which will sends them to files in your internet browser